# Assigning an enum based on the user input

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a simple console TicTacToe game. I'm trying to get the user to either select Circle or Cross to play as. I have an enum for Circle and Cross.

Everytime I run the program, I get the else output, even when I type in either "Circle" or "Cross".

Not looking for code answers, just looking to see if someone can point me in the direction of my mistake.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    private Model model;
    private Model player;

    public Game() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you want to play as Cross or Circle");
        input.nextLine();

        if(input.equals(Model.valueOf("CROSS"))) {
            player = Model.CROSS;
        } else if(input.equals(Model.valueOf("CIRCLE"))) {
            player = Model.CIRCLE;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid choice, please choose either Circle or Cross");
        }

    }
}
```

```
public enum Model {

CROSS, CIRCLE
}
```

Comment: When dealing with options in console input another method that is commonly used is to enumerate ex (1) Option A, (2) Option B... etc. The user enters the number/character associated with the option and this can often make it simpler to handle this type of situation.

Comment: In your case you can do string comparison in the if statements using `String`'s `equalsIgnoreCase` method and then you won't need to use `valueOf` you can set the value of the enum directly to `player`.

Answer (score 1):

`input` is a `Scanner` and will never be equal to an enum instance. You need to store the result of `input.nextLine()` and compare it.

```
String line = input.nextLine();
if (line.equals("CROSS")) {
  ...
} else if (line.equals("CIRCLE")) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ops, I published another solution but I miss it, upvote this :-) but I also leave mine to give some knowledge of the API and before using the method the person needs to read the doc :-)

Answer (score 1):

from JDK 11 doc the method `valueOf` of class Enum

> Returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the specified name. The name must match exactly an identifier used to declare an enum constant in this type. (Extraneous whitespace characters are not permitted.)
> Note that for a particular enum type T, the implicitly declared public static T valueOf(String) method on that enum may be used instead of this method to map from a name to the corresponding enum constant. All the constants of an enum type can be obtained by calling the implicit public static T[] values() method of that type.

Maybe you want to write your if like that

```
   String line = input.nextLine();
   if(Model.CROSS == Model.valueOf(line.trim())) {
        player = Model.CROSS;
    } else if(Model.CIRCLE == Model.valueOf(line.trim())) {
        player = Model.CIRCLE;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid choice, please choose either Circle or Cross");
    }
```

Another good point is `String line = input.nextLine();` how suggest also the other answer here

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to check if the scanner object is equal to the string value of your enum, instead save you nextLine() return value to a string variable and the check if varaiables are equal and is better to use equalsIgnoreCase

```
public Game() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Do you want to play as Cross or Circle");
    String input =  scanner.nextLine();
    if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(Model.CIRCLE.name())) {
        player = Model.CROSS;
    } else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(Model.CROSS.name())) {
        player = Model.CIRCLE;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid choice, please choose either Circle or Cross");
    }

}
```